# CVE-2022-29548 on WSO2 Identity Server 6.1.0

Tags: security, wso2, xss, wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 Identity Server 6.1.0 and in our latest scans it has been reported of containing CVE-2022-29548: WSO2 Management Console XSS. It has been tested using "GET /carbon/admin/login.jsp?login status=false&error code=%27);alert(document.domain)//". Is anyone facing a similar vulnerability and any suggestions on how can this be handled?

We tried executing GET /carbon/admin/login.jsp?login status=false&error code=%27);alert(document.domain)// and the expected result should not show an alert.

Comment: Contact the WSO2 team for more information on the matter.
Refer to https://security.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/security-reporting/report-security-issues/ for information.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was already fixed [1][2]. If you are WSO2 subscription holder please reach out WSO2 support portal to get further assists.

1. https://security.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/security-announcements/cve-to-wso2-security-advisory-mapping/
2. https://security.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/security-announcements/security-advisories/2022/WSO2-2021-1603/

Comment: We still see this issue on WSO2 IS 6.1.x on the Management Console Page. We are currently using a Community Open Source Downloaded Edition and does not hold any subscription as such.

Comment: Most of the security patches are issued via WSO2 update managers for subscription holders. Nevertheless, community users can apply the fixes themselves based on the information provided in the respective WSO2 Security Advisory.